# Symfony error installing SonataAdmin Bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I've just made a new Symfony project installation, and I'm trying to install SonataAdmin Bundle, but I'm getting this error. Can anyone tell me whats going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the requires list of the SonataAdmin Bundle [3.83](https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/admin-bundle#3.83.0) you need to have the 4.4 symfony/console version but you have 5.2 symfony. If it is a new installation i suggest to downgrade to that version and wait for the update of this bundle in 5th version in the future.